# this code is extracting the mantissa, exponent, but why are we &'ing with ptr at first and what's the value of ptr at first? 0?

Tags: c, floating-point, bitwise-operators

```
void getSME( int& s, int& m, int& e, float number )
{
    unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)&number;
```

**why did this code & ptr with number ? was this necessary and what's ptr current value? wouldn't this result in 0**

```
    s = *ptr >> 31; *getting the sign bit*
    e = *ptr & 0x7f800000;masking with exponent** 
    e >>= 23;then extracting the exponent**
    m = *ptr & 0x007fffff;*extracting mantissa*
}
```

Comment: the first line with & ptr and number is where im confused. Not sure why  that was necessary ? couldn't we have still extracted the exponent and mantissa, and sign using number ? also when you & with an unsigned int what's the result? thank you.

Comment: `ptr` is an address to `number`, but of `unsigned int` type. You do this to be able to read `number` as a bit vector, not as a `float`.

Comment: @nonDucor oh so were just converting it to an unsigned int. but why do we not want to read it as a float though ? what benefits does this give us

Comment: @DNA we want to read bitwise representation.

Comment: @DNA, bit manipulation operations are not defined for `float`s, that's why you need to cast it. Of course, as @0___________ mentioned, there are more elegant ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Although you have tagged C, this is C++ code, not C.

`unsigned int* ptr = (unsigned int*)&number;`  is an attempt to get the bits that encode the floating-point value in `number`. However, this is not a correct method in either C or C++. Better code would be `unsigned int x; memcpy(&x, &number, sizeof x);`. (For C++, use `std::memcpy`.)

In `&number`, `&` is a unary operator that produces the address of its operand, so `&number` is the address of `number`. It is a pointer to a `float`.

Then `(unsigned int*)` is a cast that converts this to a pointer to an `unsigned int`.

Then using `*ptr` uses this pointer to get an `unsigned int` from the address. The intent is that the bits that encode the `float` will be loaded from memory and interpreted as an `unsigned int`, which allows operating on those bits with the operators `>>` and `&`.

By using `unsigned int x; memcpy(&x, &number, sizeof x);` instead, the C and C++ standards ensure the bytes that represent `number` are copied into `x`. This avoids various restrictions and semantic problems in the language standards. It does require that `unsigned int` be the desired size, 32 bits. (The code also expects that the IEEE-754 binary32 format is used for `float`.)

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not the C code
2. It uses horrible pointer punning - violating the strict aliasing rule

C code:

```
void getSME( int *s, int *m, int *e, float number )
{
    union
    {
        unsigned int num;
        float fnum;
    }fu = {.fnum = number};

    *s = fu.num >> 31; //*getting the sign bit*
    *e = fu.num & 0x7f800000;  //masking with exponent** 
    *e >>= 23;   //then extracting the exponent**
    *m = fu.num & 0x007fffff; //*extracting mantissa*
}
```

or

```
void getSME( int *s, int *m, int *e, float number )
{
    unsigned int unum ; 

    memcpy(&unum, &number, sizeof(unum));

    *s = unum >> 31; //*getting the sign bit*
    *e = unum & 0x7f800000;  //masking with exponent** 
    *e >>= 23;   //then extracting the exponent**
    *m = unum & 0x007fffff; //*extracting mantissa*
}
```

Comment: too advanced for me lol I didn't understand what you said.